# Custom Runnable implementation that checks for Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() between every line of code

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I'm trying to implement a class that can manage incoming Runnables and cancel any Runnables no matter where they are in their code, guaranteed.

As an example, in Android I'd like to be able to do the following.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    manager.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            someLongRunningTaskThatCallsTheUi();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    manager.cancel(); // cancels all Runnables to avoid issues with calling the UI
}
```

How might I approach this problem when Future's `cancel()` method doesn't actually guarantee cancellation of the Runnable code and ExecutorService's `shutdownNow()` has the same issue?

From what I can see, I would need to add a check for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` before every piece of UI code that I want to call and get out of the method to avoid further calls somehow.

Comment: You *might* be able to do this with some kind of direct byte code manipulation or code weaving. These dark arts aside, what you're asking for is simply not how threads work.

Comment: I was under that impression when I came across the problem. Is there a better way to come at this then?

I want to kick off a long running operation in the background on a button click but also allow the user to back out if they want, cancelling the operation.

Comment: Are you writing these `Runnables` yourself, or are they third party plugins to your app?

Comment: I'm writing them. I just don't want to put
```if (isInterrupted) return;```
in multiple spots of the runnable. It feels like a pretty fragile way to write code.

Comment: Is there a reason `AsyncTask` won't work? Canceling it won't stop background work that doesn't check the status, but it does guarantee that no further callbacks will occur in the UI thread. For processes with multiple steps, the completion of one task could start the next.

Comment: I think I see your point. I will try to come at this from a different angle. I normally avoid AsyncTasks because I've had trouble with them in the past (like far away past) so maybe it's time to revisit them. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `AsyncTask`. Canceling an `AsyncTask` doesn't guarantee that background work will stop unless the task checks its own status. But cancellation does guarantee that `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` will not be called.  If `onProgressUpdate` is inadequate for updating your UI between steps, put each step into its own task.

Some tips for `AsyncTask`:

They've changed the default thread pool at least a couple times. If you want more control over execution, start your tasks with [`executeOnExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)).

Beware of holding onto references to the activity. A bad suggestion (popularized by a well regarded book, IIRC) says to give the task a `WeakReference` to the activity and check it before accessing the UI. This is wrong because the framework may hold a reference to the activity after calling `onDestroy`, and when it does clear its reference, the `WeakReference` will not become null until the GC notices that the activity is not strongly reachable. You should maintain a collection of running tasks inside your activity and cancel them when the activity is paused or destroyed.

To keep tasks running through configuration changes, host them in a retained headless fragment.